# Software for copy file to an Amiga floppy

Tags: windows-7, ms-dos, data-transfer, amiga

I need to copy a program to an Amiga floppy (Twin Express) but I cannot find a method how to copy it to an amiga disk, the target Amiga is an Amiga 1200 which has a workbench 3.0 system.

Any program for PC I can format a compatible floppy?

Comment: A simple google search resulted in this www.youtube.com/watch?v=bor1LyHfe0k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.amigaforever.com/kb/13-118 says

> Amiga floppy disks cannot be read on PCs without installing additional hardware such as a special floppy disk controller or a second floppy drive. As Amiga users know, this hardware incompatibility has limited Amiga-PC data sharing since the the Amiga was released in the mid-80s, and, although newer software and hardware have helped overcome this limitation, there is no way that software emulation alone can solve it: a PC cannot read Amiga disks using only the default PC floppy disk controller logic attached to a single disk drive.

Comment: thanks !. I did find somethingcalled easyADF. which is a PCMCIA kit with an Amiga floppy, it will find a compactflash drive as a harddrive, I thinkthis will suffice :)) I am waiting for the mail order to arrive now

Answer (score 3):

The pc can't read or write Amiga disks, BUT the Amiga can read PC disks. Use CrossDOS on the Amiga. If you only have a standard 880K drive on the Amiga, format a double density disk to 720K on the PC. save the file to the 720K disk - than pop it in the amiga and read the PC0 disk icon. Then you can drag & drop the file anywhere on the Amiga.
PS - you already have CrossDOS on the 3.0/3/1 OS on your A1200. Good luck